# Dynamically group fieldsets

Tags: django, django-forms, django-admin, django-views

Is there a possibility to group fieldsets dynamically? I have something like this:

```
class Category(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length= 50)

class Group(models.Model):
category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
name = ...
value = ...
...
```

With fieldsets in my AdminModel I can group them perfectly by name and value, but I want to group them after the names to get something like this:

**Category A**
name
value
**Category B**
name
value

Does anyone has an idea?

Comment: In your AdminModel class, you can overwrite `get_fieldsets(self, request, obj=None)` method and group them in any way you want. I don't fully understand second part of your question to give you more precise solution. If you need it, please add more details what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I want to group category in the Group (I updated the view for my example, it was rendered wrong). So I need something like get_fieldsets(..)  fieldsets = ("Category A",{'fields': Category.objects.filter(name =="A")) and so on